# Set Up a Timer That Runs for the Life of an IOS App

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, timer

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a timer that begins at the time that an app is installed and continues to run even when the app is in the background. I'm basically using the timer to periodically check the battery life of an external device that is linked to the phone. I've been told that the best way to do this is to use some sort of delegate calls to a timer function, but I'm fairly new to IOS and am pretty confused on how to do that. I know how to set up the timer and get the battery life, I'm however perplexed on how to keep the timer going through the life of the app. Any help you could give would be extreeemely appreciated! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running an app in the background (forever) isn't possible.

But while your app is running... you can set the `repeats` parameter of the method `scheduledTimerWithInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` to `YES`.

Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) to running it in the background for a certain period of time to perform a relatively large task.

Comment: Thank you! The Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks section applies directly to what I'm doing!

Comment: That's fine. And glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

> run even when the app is in the background

Not possible. You can request an extra 10 minutes, but thats it. You will not be able to write your app as is.

For the timer part of your question, you can do this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(checkBattery:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

But you should really be subscribing to the notifications on battery change events. [Here is sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BatteryStatus/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008812) from apple that shows how to do it.

Comment: Why is that not possible? I'm looking to create something similar to a service in Android. i.e. the app is running, but may not currently be at the forefront, but still does stuff in the background. Doesn't ios have that type of functionality?

Comment: Apple doesn't allow it. The best you can do is start the time when your app enters the foreground.

Comment: Then how is it that apps like Spotify allow you to continue playing music when the app isn't at the forefront? Is it just different for music so that you can take over the system audio? Is there not some sort of workaround there?

Comment: There are certain categories of apps that are allowed: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22 Yours is not one of them. I would highly suggest reading the iPhone Programming Guide.

Answer (score 0):

coneybeare is right. This is iOS policy, which is in place exactly to prevent what you are trying to do, i.e. exhaust the iPhone's (or iPad's) battery life.

Comment: I want to be able to alert the user every couple hours if my Battery Check results in a low battery. Do have any suggestions on how this could be accomplished?